# Recursive function and performance in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I am new to C++, I would appreciate if anyone and help me to validate the below function or help me improve it.

```
void RecursiveKnn(std::set<PointId> &refSet, const PointId &id, const KD3Index &kid, int const lvl)
{
    if (refSet.find(id) == refSet.end())
        refSet.insert(id);

    if (lvl < m_knn)
    {
        auto ids = kid.neighbors(id, 7);
        for (auto x : ids)
        {
            if (x == id)
                continue;
            RecursiveKnn(refSet, x, kid, lvl+1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a recursive function to run and generate a set of hierarchical objects. basically, start with one object, get next/nearby objects and so on for the next level. Along with it, I want to avoid duplicates as well. The levels are limited to 3 - 4 and do not expect to go any further.

This function is called millions of time and is taking forever to run. I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest any improvement. On top of my head I am sure `std::set` is not the correct data structure to use but, I don't know what to use.

EDIT: The reason, I find the function to have the performance problem is that. At first I have a single function with 3 nested for loop. which worked within reasonable time. When I changed it to a recursive function, The process did not complete for more than an hour.

Comment: What did you find when you profiled your application? Why is `std::set` not the correct structure? We have no idea what are your purposes and requirements.

Comment: At a guess, your performance issue comes not from the recursion as such but from the call to `kid.neighbors()`.

Comment: Well, based on the above std::unordered_set would be better because std::set's orderedness doesnt seem to matter.

Comment: What is the average number of neighbors each PointId has?

Comment: What optimization level did you build with, and how did you profile?

Comment: It's not like that recursion alone resulted in that long time, most times invalid recursion results in stack overflow; Profile the function.

Comment: @SergeyA is `std::set` like hashset in C#? If not that itself will increase the performance of `find` from O(log n) to O(1).
@jwezorek the neighbors are controlled by how much you want, in the function is 6 (+1 for the id itself) 
As I said, I am new to C++, not sure how to profile. will add more info why I think the function is cause of concern.

Comment: Can item A be neighbors to item B and item C also neighbors to item B? I think your data structure doesnt have cycles from children to parents i.e. it a DAG but that doesnt mean it is impossible to not explore the same node multiple times. Your test (x == id) just tests that you do not re=explore a parent but what about re-exploring a child you already explored when exploring another parent?

Comment: Although there is certainly room for optimization, the fact that it takes forever is a logical bug : I have the impression the recursion can jump from one item to a neighboring one, and then back again. That results in an infinite loop. @jwezorek you beat me to it

Comment: std::set is a binary search tree i.e. O(log n) lookups. std::unordered_set is a hash table.

Comment: @jwezorek I think you have a point there, I should skip the whole funcation if It is already in the set

Comment: Just so you know, if you have a really large data structure a recursive function like this might still become problematic : the program stack grows with a collection of neighbors for each level of recursion.

Comment: You probably want to return right away if id is found in the reference set, otherwise you are going to find the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more information my guess would be that multiple PointIds can be neighbors with the same PointIds, even though there is a parent/child relation that holds.

In other words, this code is performing a depth-first search on a directed acyclic graph but is not checking for revisits the way a typical depth-first search does. This means you will be exploring the same nodes many times which is extremely inefficient.

Change

```
if (refSet.find(id) == refSet.end())
    refSet.insert(id);
```

to

```
if (refSet.find(id) != refSet.end())
    return;
refSet.insert(id);
```

Also you should use an std::unordered_set instead of an std::set but that is a lesser concern if the above is true.

Comment: Your concern is very well possible. Also, is `if(refSet.insert(id).second){ ..recursive. }` is same as you suggestion and is it better or worse for perfomance.

Comment: I dont think that is the same because I think insert will return the inserted item whether it is there or not ... you would want .insert to return something that evaluates to false in the case where it is already there ... if i understamd your question. But regardless if your code is really exploring the same nodes multiple times that behavior would dwarf individual mico-optimizations anyway as if it is rexploring the the same nodes multiple times its formal time complexity is worse than it needs to be.

Comment: You may be able to take advantage of [`std::set::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert)'s return value to simplify this further.

Comment: @jwezorek `insert` returns iterator to the item (inserted or not) and flag if insertion did happen. So this way is more efficient - not doing 2 lookups in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

This is wasteful.

```
if (refSet.find(id) == refSet.end())
    refSet.insert(id);
```

There's no need to check if something is a member of a set before inserting it, just insert it anyway.

```
refSet.insert(id);
```

That said this is not an order of magnitude improvement.

This might also help

```
const auto& ids = kid.neighbors(id, 7);
```

Depends on what `neighbors` returns but it looks like you're copying some collection or other.

Comment: Second one hardly will help if `neighbors` returns by value, and it is very likely so

Comment: @Slava Yes well the OP can at least look at that area. They might need to adjust their API.

Comment: Not sure how you can adjust here, looks like that method calculates result so unlikely it can return const reference, anyway due to move semantics I doubt that  will help significantly or at all.

Comment: So if I just `insert` it will not create duplicates?